# Remove substracted paths from shape layers and combine into one shape layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, icon, layers, shapes

I'm creating a wi-fi icon in Photoshop, using three circles and subtracted paths.

Now I need to remove the subtracted area and combine the three shape layers into one shape layer without rasterizing.

This is what I want to do:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: If the wifi icon is all you need and not so much the technique there are many resources that will provide this icon and it is actually a Creative Commons asset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed it myself.

There is a combine Button in the toolbar you can see once clicked the path direction tool. Select the layer and click combine, That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the Pen Tool to add anchors at correct points along the angle, delete portions of the paths you do not want, then use the Pen Tool to Option/Alt-click anchors and join paths of the arcs.

Once that's done, you can copy/paste paths to the same vector layer.

Photoshop does not offer any features to remove portions of shapes/paths automatically such as the Pathfinder operations in Illustrator or Indesign.

10 second job in Illustrator = 5-10 minutes in Photoshop.

Comment: well, i don't have illustrator license...

Comment: It can be done in Photoshop. You just have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop CC, with the merged shape layer selected, select the path selection tool:

[image]

Then select path operations in the options toolbar:

[image: Photoshop CC Toolbar]

Then select merge shape components:

[image]

It'll throw a popup asking you to confirm:

[image]

Once you confirm, it'll combine everything into one nice path.