# Combine Two Vector Shapes into One, With One Path (in Sketch App)

Tags: vector, sketch-app

(In Sketch, the app.)

I'm trying to create a shape that is symmetrical on the vertical axis.

I made one half of the shape, duplicated it, flipped the duplicate, then grouped the two together into one object using the `Union` join menu option.

This is almost what I want, except that when displaying the border for the object, the vertical line where I joined the two objects still appears.

Is there a way to combine the two union'ed vector shapes so that one vector path goes around the outside outline?

I believe the equivalent in Photoshop is [the `Merge Shape Components` option](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19632/remove-substracted-paths-from-shape-layers-and-combine-into-one-shape-layer). I can't seem to find the equivalent in Sketch.

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/34879/how-can-i-connect-two-disjoint-paths-in-sketch-app

Answer (score 26):

1. Select the layers that you wish to combine.
2. Press the "Union" button in the tool bar, or from the to menu, choose Layer > Combine > Union. (You already got to this point, of course.)
3. Layer > Paths > Flatten will merge the shapes into the same path.

Comment: This should be the solution, but it doesn't always work for me. Sometimes the paths don't merge. Any ideas?

Comment: This does not work seem to work for me either.

Comment: Mark Nugent's answer works great under the following conditions: - The shapes overlap somewhere. If they don't, flattening won't do anything. - Make sure the shapes you want to merge are in their own group. No shapes with layer combine type subtract, intersect or difference should be in that group. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Bramchi I still do not get the option to flatten when these conditions are met.

Comment: `Flatten` moved - now you go to Layer > Combine > Flatten

Answer (score 7):

Came here looking for an answer, but stumbled upon the solution myself while working through the one suggested here.

Select your shapes/paths and "Join" them: Layer > Paths > Join.

Comment: Please what is the difference between `Join` and `flatten`?

Comment: That's a good question @Kurt. Just based on the results I assume a Join actually combines the shapes into a single shape, while Flatten seems to simply combine them into a multi-layer shape. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Join seems to work better for me