# How to make a larger arrowed, double arrow line in Sketch App?

Tags: sketch-app

I'm trying to make a double sided arrow that can expand and contract like a line can.

I've trying to stick a triangle to a line but I'm not sure how, I like how the line is able to pivot back and forth as shown below, however it doesn't bring the triangle with it.

If I group them together then I can't pivot the line.

I read in [another post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46200/combine-two-vector-shapes-into-one-with-one-path-in-sketch-app) to use `Layer > Paths > Join` or `Layer > Paths > Flatten` however when I select both my line and my triangle neither of those two options are available to me.

I've tried a double arrowed line, however I can't adjust the size.

I've also tried to use the [arrowify](https://github.com/joclin/arrowfy) plugin, however it seems like it is also just a triangle that is grouped with a line

Would appreciate some guidance

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seem that the problem is caused by some kind of snapping tool. I just tried to re-create the issue you described but there is no any problem with creating and rotating arrows in my Sketch app. Please watch this short screencast: http://quick.as/qJo6H9Y8w

Maybe you have some snapping plugin installed? I'd recommend to disable all your plugins and enable them one after another to explore which of them caused this issue.

Hope this helps :)